# In moment.js, is it possible to have a date-time string and keep the date but change the time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and want to update a date-time string with a new user-entered time. The date has not changed, only the time. There is no timezone change, just that the hour and minute values have possibly been altered.

How would I take a string like this and convert it such that the time is different?

This is would I'd expect:

```
const dateTimeString = '2017-11-14T16:04:54.0086709-06:00'
const newDateTimeString = (
    moment(dateTimeString)
    .changeTime('05:20 PM')
    .format()
)
// newDateTimeString === '2017-11-14T17:20:00.0086709-06:00'
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Moment docs? The library exposes all the basic setter functions from the native Date prototype, so you can create a date and then set the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user-entered time is formatted as such `13:00` you could do :

```
   const dateTimeString = '2017-11-14T16:04:54.0086709-06:00'
var userInput = "13:20"
    const newDateTimeString = (
        moment(dateTimeString)
        .hours(userInput.split(":")[0])
        .minutes(userInput.split(":")[1])
        .format()
    )
```

Using https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/ and https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/

If it's formatted with PM and AM system, you could to the same, but with a little bit more of parsing, to know if it's 5.00 AM or PM.

Comment: Using that logic, we could just do `moment('05:20 PM')` and then grab the `.hours()` and `.minutes()` off if it without parsing extra right?

Comment: @Sawtaytoes I don't know if moment accept "5:20 PM" as a constructor argument, but if it does, your idea is what you need, try it :)

Comment: You'd have to do it like this: `moment('5:20 PM', "hh:mm A")`.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes check VincenzoC answer I upvoted, I think it's what you need

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function like `changeTime`, you can write your own using [`set`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/).

You can add `changeTime` using [`moment.fn`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

> The `Moment` prototype is exposed through `moment.fn`. If you want to add your own functions, that is where you would put them.

You can create a temp moment object with your "time to add" value using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), then use [`set(Object(String, Int))`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) and getters like [`hours()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/) and [`minutes()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/).

Here a live sample:

```js
moment.fn.changeTime = function(timeString) {
  let m1 = moment(timeString, 'hh:mm A');
  return this.set({h: m1.hours(), m: m1.minutes()});
}

const dateTimeString = '2017-11-14T16:04:54.0086709-06:00'
const newDateTimeString = (
    moment(dateTimeString)
    .changeTime('05:20 PM')
    .format()
)

console.log(newDateTimeString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @VincenzoC. I wasn't actually wanting to copy that exact API though. The `format` function actually does what I want without having to expand `moment` using `fn`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use moment to grab the date and then combine it with your custom time value in another `moment()` call like so:

```
const newDateTimeString = (
    moment(`${moment(dateTimeString).format('YYYY-MM-DD')} 05:20 PM`)
    .format()
)
```

Comment: This code will produce Deprecation warning since the input is not in a recognized format (ISO 8601 or RFC 2822), see [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) to read about recognized formats and, in your case, use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead.