# Combine Moment object with a time string to get a new moment object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a moment object and a seperate time string like this:

```
var selectedDay = moment();
var time = '6 PM';
```

I want to combine the 2 I can't figure it out from the documentation, something like this.

```
var actualMoment = moment(selectedDay).setTime(time);
```

The `time` variable could be values like the following: `6 AM, 5 PM, 4:30 PM` I could potentially change the format of the `time` variable if it makes it easier, but the two values still need to be seperate variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In moment.js, is it possible to have a date-time string and keep the date but change the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296435/in-moment-js-is-it-possible-to-have-a-date-time-string-and-keep-the-date-but-ch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension to your script:

```
moment.fn.setTime(str, format){
    var timeParsed = moment(str, format);
    if(timeParsed.isValid() == true)
    {
        return this.hour(timeParsed.hour())
                   .minute(timeParsed.minute())
                   .second(timeParsed.second());
    } else {
        console.warning(" Time couldn't be parsed: " + str + " (format: " format + ")";
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then use it as you used in your example:

```
var selectedDay = moment();
var time = '6 PM';    
var actualMoment = selectedDay.setTime(time, 'h A');
```